# SharedPreferences does not apply() or commit() inside a service with its own process

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I have a `Service` which has its own process:

```
<service
    android:name=".services.Commander"
    android:label="@string/commander"
    android:process=":commander_process" >
</service>
```

inside this service an `AsyncTask` is executed using `executeOnExecutor`. Inside its `onPostExecute` method I want to write data using the following code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_APP_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString(Constants.PREF_KEY_APP_PASSWORD, MD5.get(password)).apply();
```

But, this code has no effect and prefs won't update. I also tried `commit()` rather than `apply()` and it didn't work, too. Then I tried `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` instead of `MODE_PRIVATE`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_APP_KEY", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

it didn't work.

My code works on Android 2.3.6, but it wouldn't work on Android 4.2.2. How can I fix it?

Comment: SharedPreferences prefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyService.this); does this work for you?

Comment: @IllegalArgument let me check

Comment: @IllegalArgument it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `SharedPreferences` is not `process-safe` even after using `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`. So I ran the `Service` with the same process as my main activity and now it works properly. I changed the code in `manifest` xml:

```
<service
    android:name=".services.Commander"
    android:label="@string/commander" >
</service>
```